# ASP.NET MVC Upload file time out

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I currently have an ASP.NET MVC project that has file uploading and it works great if the user has a good enough connection and their file is of a reasonable size.

The problem I'm running into is that sometimes a user might have a 56k connection (how they can live with it in this day and age, I don't know) or are uploading a larger file or some combination of the two.

I'd like to keep a small timeout for normal pages (90 seconds or so), but allow for a larger timeout for actions where a user is uploading. This is just one action, so I don't mind putting code inside just that singular action rather than a generic solution.

Ultimately, a solution that would automatically increase the timeout if Request.Files.Count > 0 would be the best.

Comment: I'm on dial-up. I live in Jamaica.

Comment: What is timing out?  If you're not getting anything from the client after 90 seconds or so, you're probably not going to successfully upload anything.

Comment: I am continuously receiving data, chris, but sending even 10 megs over 56k will take over 90 seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would work in an MVC project, but you could try creating a location in your web.config and set the execution timeout for just your upload URL.  For example:

```
<location path="YourUrl">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="9001"/>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

Comment: This works. You can also add maxRequestLength here (on the httpRuntime tag) if you want to allow larger requests to the upload handler only.

Comment: his execution timeout is over 9000!

Comment: 9000 seconds is 2 ½ hours! What a timeout.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to increase the timeout in web.config:

```
<httpRuntime executionTimeout="01:00:00" />
```

Now this is overridable in sub web.config files meaning that if you want to increase the timeout only for the uploading script you could write a generic HTTP handler that will handle the uploads and put it in its own subfolder with its own web.config.

Answer (score 0):

Possible issue: If its not a timeout because of the zero activity, maybe its something to do with the built in size restriction, in the web.config `httpRuntime` section you could add/increase `maxRequestLength=""` to your size limit